# Laravel php database check the date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is there the proper way to check the database date if smaller than "before date" then do the restriction?

currently What I have is

```
        if (count(Sale::where('date','<=' ,'2018-08-01')->get()) > 0 ) {
            echo "Sales is closed";
            return false;
        }else {
            echo "Sales is open";
            return true;
        }
```

The sale will closed for the date that before 2018-08-01 and new sale will open after the date.

Comment: If you want to include records which are strictly _earlier_ than 1st August 2018, then use `date < '2018-08-01'`.  But, it is not entirely clear what your problem is.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Just now the restriction won't affect if I set date < '2018-08-01'. This question has been solved but another problem is now restriction will affect if > '2018-08-01'. It shouldn't take effect more than the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes proper method in laravel-4  but directly used `count` method  u can achieve (`get` method is not needed here)

```
if (Sale::where('date','<=' ,'2018-08-01')->count() > 0 ) {
    //restriction
}else {
   //not restrication 
}
```